# How to remove dashes in numbers WITHOUT removing leading zeros

Tags: xslt, transformation, dt, workday-api

The input (account numbers) I have are currently in the format **005-947864-296**, I'm using the translate function to remove dashes as follows: *<xsl:value-of select="translate(($account_number), '-', '')"/>* The problem is that the output I'm getting in the csv is **5947864296** (which is removing Leading Zeros). How do I remove the dashes WITHOUT removing the leading zeros?

I'm using XSLT 2.0 and I tried both translate and replace functions but getting the same result!

Comment: The translate operation you show does NOT remove leading zeros. Please provide a way to reproduce the problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: The leading zeroes won't be lost if you keep it as a string. But if you try to make it an integer, those will be lost.

Comment: Possibly the values are not quoted in the output CSV and therefore interpreted as numbers by the target application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are viewing the generated CSV by loading it into a spreadsheet program such as Microsoft Excel? Excel (notoriously) assumes that if a field is all-numeric, leading zeroes are insignificant and can be discarded (which is not the case for things such as account numbers).

The problem isn't with your XSLT code generating the CSV, it's with the application you are using to read/process the CSV.

Comment: *"The problem isn't with your XSLT code generating the CSV,"* I would wait to see the entire code before making such statement.

Comment: I tried opening the csv file using notepad++ and the leading zeros ARE THERE! you are right, it was excel being so "smart" removing leading zero's from account numbers. I can't thank you enough.